# PHP how to get most relevant search result?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code which picks the most views three results from a MYSQL table and displays them.

```
<?php

$currentname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `entree` ORDER BY views DESC Limit 1,3");

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($currentname)) {
  $title = $row[0];
  $ID = $row[2];
  $views = $row[4];
  $user = $row[5];
  $type = $row[8];
  $realid = $row[7];
  $srcIMG = $row[6];
  $srcExt = $row[3];
  $SRC = "img/tempXL.png";

  echo "<div id = \"featureArt\" align=\"left\" >
  <a href=\"".$url."\"><img src=\"$SRC\" alt = \"article thumbnail\" id=\"titleimgArt\"/></a><div id = \"feature2_1\"><a href= \"$url\" id = \"titletext\" alt = \"article title\">$donetitle</a></div></div>";
}
?>
```

This works great but I want to have a string, lets say it contains "Cool Netflix Movies". I want to search the table for anything with the title "Cool Netflix Movies". If there isn't any I want to get the closest thing to that which might be just "10 Netflix series" for example. If there were two similar entries and the second has "Netflix movies" in it, it should take priority over the first. How can I accomplish this, How can I get the most relevant results?

Comment: Thats not so easy. A good start would be to take a look at `SQL LIKE` and `SQL Wildcards`

Comment: i know about MySQL LIKE

Answer (score 1):

See on full text search:

- [Full-Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)
- [Natural Language Full-Text Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)
- [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/latest/index.html)